# Выравнивание window.open() по центру

Tags: javascript

```
window.open('url', 'test', 'width=860, height=470, resizable=yes, scrollbars=no, status=yes');
```

Сейчас окошко отображается в левом углу. А как сделать его по центру?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.open('index.php', 'test', 'width=860, height=470, top='+((screen.height-470)/2)+',left='+((screen.width-860)/2)+', resizable=yes, scrollbars=no, status=yes');
```

Comment: @Deonis, огромное спасибо!